# Neo4j 3.1.1 ConsistencyCheck errors

Tags: neo4j

I'm running into some errors during ConsistencyCheck, using Neo4j Enterprise 3.1.1

Here's is a sample:

```
ERROR: The relationship count does not correspond with the expected count.
        CountsEntry[RelationshipKey[()-->(:label=48)]: 68720069575]
        Inconsistent with: 592848
```

What does this error mean and what could cause it?

---

I found a possible solution using [store-utils](https://github.com/jexp/store-utils).

I also found an easier solution than copying the whole store using store-utils, by deleting the `neostore.counts.db*` files (note the wildcard), located under my database dir.

I still want to know what could cause the inconsistency.

Comment: There are no count-store related fixes in the 3.1.x releases, there are a couple in the 3.2.x releases (see https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-3.2-changelog). Not sure if any relates to your issue though. Anyway, since you are running Enterprise and thus have support ... why not log an issue ?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I got a pretty fast answer at neo4j-users's slack channel, deleting the files mentioned in the update worked perfectly. I'm still wondering how this happen in my db though.